# Gravity in Match 3 gamet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am building a match 3 game in Action Script 3. When a match occurs all the matching blocks get removed. but how can I make the top blocks above the removed blocks fall?

Comment: Are your blocks stored in some kind of grid data structure, like a multi-dimensional array ?

Comment: yes, I using a two dimensional array to store the blocks.

Comment: So using your grid and 'math' , you should be able to calculate where the block should fall to. 1) remove the blocks from the grid data structure 2) calculate where each block should fall to and update the grid 3) execute the movement.